# extract text from tag

Tags: php

Hi I've got these lines here, I am trying to extract the first paragraph found in the file, but this fails to return any results, if not it returns results that are not even in `<p>` tags which is odd?

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$hd = fopen($file,'r');
$cn = fread($hd, filesize($file));
fclose($hd);

$cnc = preg_replace('/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/','$1',$cn);
```

Comment: Watch out for people requesting files that are not files you wish to serve. Users might request "foo.html", but some users are not so nice.

Comment: how could i go about parsing out "bad" requests?

Comment: Don't. Use a whitelist of allowed files. Ensuring the file has an acceptable extension (e.g. `html`), and the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_\.]` ought to do the trick, and check that it contains only a single period, and that period immediately precedes the extension. Or something like that. I'm sure someone with more experience with these things might be able to help you out (or post a separate question).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://localhost/foo.php");
preg_match('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/', $html, $match);
echo($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [DOM parsing](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for that:

```
// SimpleHtmlDom example
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/blah.php');

// Find all paragraphs 
foreach($html->find('p') as $element) 
       echo $element->innerText() . '<br>';
```

It would allow you to more reliably replace some of the markup:

```
$html->find('p', 0)->innertext() = 'foo';
```

Comment: PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser can be installed with Composer. This one has Composer autoloading: https://packagist.org/packages/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser