# Extracting specific text from a link or paragraph or title or alt tag and show it again on same page but different location

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, extract

I'm trying to duplicate/show the text **Java Bean** in another part (under the image) on the same page (visit http://www.miracleflooring.ca/cork.html to see how that works). Right now I have the info title & price show when you hover over the thumbnail, when mouse out, info hides.

My client asked me to show the title & price under each image (each div with class item) and I want to find a way to do that without having to re-do things manually for each item.
Is there a way using css/javascript/php of doing so (I hope I'm clear on what I need to do).

```
<div class="item">
     <a href="#"><img src="imgs/products/cork/java-bean.jpg" alt="Java Bean" width="132" height="132" /></a>
     <div class="caption">
          <a href="imgs/products/cork/java-bean.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[cork]" title="Java Bean">Java Bean</a>
          <p class="price">$4.99 sq-ft</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I know some of the code seems like overkill but it was done that way and will take lots of work to change that.

I have no idea on how to do this and I'm still not sure what is the best way to do it as well but any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:** I saw karim79 answering something that may help but not sure if that's what I need (how to implement it too) [extract text from tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612653/extract-text-from-tag)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want but maybe I can help you in the right direction: what about: var x = document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML; var y = document.createElement("div"); y.innerHTML = x; document.getElementById("item").appendChild(y); You'll have the caption twice. Only problem here is that your elements do not have ids :) , but it's a bit of code that might give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS:

```
.item {position: relative; margin-bottom: 30px;}
.item .caption {position: absolute; bottom: -20px;}
```

That should get close enough to tweak it further yourself. The "margin-bottom" will expand the space available under each item, and a larger negative "bottom" will move the caption text lower down.

Comment: This is only going to move the text below (and remove it from the boxes on hover all together). I'm looking to keep the one on hover but also show the title & price below each box. Almost like duplicating the text. I guess I can try using something like this content: "\title and price here"; on the a:after and see what happens

Comment: Given that you want new text and hover, I think your best bet may be to just fix this manually. As these are look like static HTML pages, you should be able to achieve this with a couple of Find & Replace's.