# preg_match does not match in PHP, although the regular expression seems to be correct

Tags: php, preg-match

I am doing

```
preg_match("/\<\/p\> (\d*?) /", $error, $matches)
```

where `$error="bla-bla-bla </p> 12345 bla-bla-bla"`

The weird this is that it does not find a match, even though I double-checked the regular expression.

Why doesn't it work?

Here is the complete code:

```
            $values=$form->getValue();
            $url = "http://something.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml";
            $request = "<helpdesk_ticket><description>".$values['subject']."</description><email>".$username."</email></helpdesk_ticket>"; 
            echo $request;
            $headers = array('Content-Type: application/xml','Content-Length: ' . strlen($request));
            var_dump($headers);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'email@email.com:password');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
//          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
//          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 

            $http_result = curl_exec($ch);
            $error       = curl_error($ch);
            $http_code   = curl_getinfo($ch ,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            curl_close($ch);

            if ($error) {
              print "<br /><br />$error";
            } else {
              if (preg_match("/\<\/p\> (\d*?) /", $error, $matches)) {
                $ticket_id = $matches[1];
                print "Ticket submitted: $ticket_id\n";
              }
              print "<br /><br />Location header not found";
              var_dump($matches);
              var_dump($http_result);
              echo $error;
              echo $http_result;
```

Comment: there is a error in you $error, should be $error = (assignment) not == (comparison)...

Comment: This is always a good tool to know to know whether or not the regex is actually wrong: http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester/?pattern=%2F\%3C\%2Fp\%3E+%28\d*%3F%29%2F&subject=bla-bla-bla+%3C%2Fp%3E+12345+bla-bla-bla in which case as @webarto says above it is the code itself, in this case the assignment. Process of elimination

Comment: webarto: in fact $error = (assignment) has been used for assignment correctly, I meant ($error == (expression)) is True

Comment: @JacobM: Do you wish to extract text within a `<p>` tag from the HTML string? Why not use Dom parsing if so? example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612653/extract-text-from-tag

Comment: @Sammaye: also, I have tried a tool like the one you have suggested, and it works fine: Array
(
    [0] => </p> 12345 
    [1] => 12345
)

Comment: `var_dump(0 == "bla-bla-bla </p> 12345 bla-bla-bla");` is `true`... so we could only guess...

Comment: `0` ? what is `0`? That is not a valid var name, try var_dumping the $matches var from the poreg_match.

Comment: @verisimilitude No, I am not trying to extract text from a proper DOM structure. I am using a Ruby on Rails (I think) web service that returns an error string that has a bunch of stuff, I am trying to get the variable that follows </p>

Comment: @Sammaye `var_dump($error = 0 == "bla-bla-bla </p> 12345 bla-bla-bla");`

Comment: @webarto Yes, this is exactly the reason I was stuck on this for the last hour

Comment: @webarto Oops thought it was OP who posted that :P

Comment: @Sammaye Yep, I tried var_dumping the $matches, I get an empty array

Comment: @JacobM it matches. Could you show your **complete** code?

Comment: @webarto @Sammaye Right, I should have used inline code `(
    [0] => </p> 22 
    [1] => 22
)` That's what I got

Comment: @JacobM result is in `$matches[1]` (first group)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I just added the complete code

Comment: @webarto It does, in the online regex testing tool! But not when I test in on the website I am working on

Comment: @JacobM enable error reporting, it is impossible and most likely `E_PEBKAC`...

Comment: I see a weirdness in your code. It will never run the preg_match if `if ($error) {` could it be that the preg_match is never running?

Comment: @JacobM if ( ! emtpy($error)) ... and what Sammaye says, it never runs...

Comment: @webarto @Sammaye I just looked over it, indeed `if ($error) {` is not quite right. But still, preg_match does run, and it does not find the match

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is correct and it certainly matches.  Your problem is that you didn't execute the regular expression on response of the http. Use `$http_result` instead of `$error`

```
preg_match("/\<\/p\> (\d*)/", $http_result, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I should have used `htmlspecialchars()` on `$error`

Comment: shouldn't you execute `preg_match` against `$http_result` instead of `$error`?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Yes, that too. First time working with CURL and XML and all that stuff, messed my head up